# Using the selected state of a Android Toggle button / switch

Tags: android

I am looking to add a toggle button or switch to my current app. What i am wanting to do is write the current clicked state to a string so that this can be called back later by another part of the app.

what i will ultimately be doing with this is using the selected item from my spinner, and then the state of my switch to combine the two and write this to a text file or Db.

So the spinner works and writes and i can save its selected state as follows.

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            SelectedServer = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }
```

so when i go to save this later in my code i can call the SelectedServer string to save this data.

My question is how can i replicate this for a switch, where one state will be for true and save the value &true, and the other for false and save the value &false to be called later.

the reason for this is that, the saved value will be added later to the selected item from the spinner.

all help, advise appreciated

Dave

**** savesettings event

```
    public void saveSettings(View view) {

    File txtFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFolder/");
    if (!txtFolder.exists()) {
        txtFolder.mkdir();
    }
    File file = new File(txtFolder, "setting.txt");
    String.valueOf(SelectedServer.getBytes());
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(SelectedServer.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Setting Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

So what i am looking to do is where i have

```
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(SelectedServer.getBytes());
```

I will be adding the state of the toggle switch, so was looking at something like fos.write(SelectedServer+SelectedState.getBytes());

but that doesn't seem to work, is there a way to join these to saved strings together like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android Developer library there is a good example of a toggle switch. 
(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

Setting setOnCheckedChangeListener will allow you to change the string.

```
    String toggleisChecked;
    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);

toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
//Set the string to true
        toggleIsChecked = "true";

    } else {
        // Set the string to false
        toggleIsChecked = "false";
    }
}
```

});

I'm not quite sure from your question whether you're also asking how to combine two values into the same string so the quickest explanation is to create a String in your resources such as:

```
<string name="current_states">%1$s &amp; %2$s</string>
```

Then when setting that string you would add your two values like so:

```
String whateverYouWantToShow;
whateverYouWantToShow = getString(R.string.current_states, SelectedServer, toggleIsChecked);
```

This places the values into the string resource.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I will test that shortly.

What i was referring to in regards to adding 2 strings together is my save setting event is added above.